# Two adverbs connected with and

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Eat less greasy food and high calorie foods.

Does the it mean that, eat high calorie foods and eat less greasy food?

Answer (score 2):

No, it means to eat less of both.

View it as a list:

> Eat less:
>   - greasy food
>   - high calorie foods.

It wouldn't make sense to include both positives and negatives in the same list or sentence without making it very clear, for example:

> Eat **less** greasy food, and **more** leafy vegetables.

(Plus, the fact that both greasy foods and high-calorie foods are generally considered to be bad for weight loss makes the intended meaning of your example obvious)